# Smallest GUI VNC setup

Tags: gnome, memory, vnc

I'm setting up VNC on my VPS with 768mb ram.
What would be the best setup to save the most memory?
Right now I tried Gnome-core with `vncserver` but it uses a lot of RAM.

I remember having a VNC running on only 512Mb with no problem.
But on this new one I'm getting errors all the time because it's used up all my RAM.

Comment: Run `htop`, press F6 to sort by memory usage and check what processes are using memory. When you identify these processes we could propose you some replacements.

Comment: cant run htop from VNC, cant start any programs without getting: 
Failed to fork (Cannot allocate memory)
So have to be somthing i can run from ssh session

Comment: You can run `htop` from ssh session.

Comment: hmm im just getting "command not found"?
Running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: Try `top` and when it starts press M (Shift + m)...

Comment: Heres the result:
http://pastebin.com/WT1J9Grt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `top` output that you posted it is clear that you have only 16 megabytes of free RAM.

There is no single process that is using your RAM - GNOME starts many components - and most of the processes that are visible on list comes from GNOME session.

I see two solutions:

- remove X and use console only environment
- install some lightweight WM

Depending on the purpose of that VPS you should choose solution. If you want to run on it some services that doesn't need X, and you installed X and GNOME to "simplify" management just remove it. Install `mc` for file management and `mcedit` or `nano` as editor.

If X is required to run some software on VPS remove GNOME and all stuff installed by GNOME (you have `cups` running on server - it's unnecessary unless you have printer connected to VPS ;)) and install some lightweight WM like `fluxbox` or `fvwm`.

Comment: Perfect! used fluxbox instead, worked like a charm!